# Python Gtk3 - Custom Statusbar w/ Progressbar

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, gtk3, statusbar

Currently I am working to learn how to use Gtk3 with Python 3.6. So far I have been able to use a combination of resources to piece together a project I am working on, some old 2.0 references, some 3.0 shallow reference guides, and using the python3 interpreters help function.

However I am stuck at how I could customise the statusbar to display a progressbar. Would I have to modify the contents of the statusbar to add it to the end(so it shows up at the right side), or is it better to build my own statusbar?

Also how could I modify the progressbars color? Nothing in the materials list a method/property for it.

Comment: Concerning your second question: 1) It's a good practice to ask only one question at a time 2) you should dig into gtk css rules. It allows you to modify some properties at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GtkStatusbar is a subclass of GtkBox. You can use any GtkBox method including `pack_start` and `pack_end` or even `add`, which is a method of GtkContainer.

Thus you can simply add you progressbar to statusbar.

Comment: This makes things easier. I could subclass Gtk.StatusBar and add my extra widgets in the __init__ method and add helper methods easily now. Thanks